# Adding textbox shadow without focusing

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, registration

If any fields in registration form are not filled, then that fields should show a red shadow around the text and disable the submit button until all fields are filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in **CSS**

```
.error {
  -moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 2px 2px #F00;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px #F00;
  box-shadow:         1px 1px 2px 2px #F00;
}
```

And in **Script** like

```
$('input').removeClass('error');
if(validation===true)// in case of validation error
{
   $('#inputId').addClass('error');
   $('#submitId').prop('disabled',true);
}
else
{
    $('#submitId').prop('disabled',false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, apply a class for error inputs (although some validation frameworks take care of this, just get the error elements) then use jQuery to style those elements.

```
    $(".myErrorInputsClass").css("box-shadow", "1px 1px 1px blue");
    //repeat for webkit, moz etc
```